# Entity count with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this query that gives me a list of all clubs that a users is a member of. There are 3 entities User, Club, ClubMember. There is a many-to-many, with ClubMember as the association between club and user.

```
 var clubs = db.Users
               .Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
               .SelectMany(u => u.ClubMembers)
               .Select(m => m.Club)
               .ToList();
```

On each row of the table I will include a link to show the other members of the club. So the table row would look something like this;

```
Club1 - This is club one - "show all members"
Club2 - This is club two - "show all members"
```

Now what I would like to do is include in the "show all members" link, is to include the count of the members, so it will look like this.

```
Club1 - This is club one - "show all members (25)"
Club2 - This is club two - "show all members (14)"
```

So my question is how can I modify the query to return the total number of members in each club?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably safe to say that there also exists a List of ClubMembers on the Club object as well. As such you should have your query statement be like this:

```
var clubs = db.Users
.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
.SelectMany(u => u.ClubMembers)
.Select(m => new SomeType{ Club = m.Club, NumberOfMembers = m.Club.ClubMembers.Count()})
.ToList();
```